# How to create a Graph for a Uniform-cost Search in C++

Tags: c++, search, artificial-intelligence

Could anyone please help me how to graph a tree in C++ if I have the following input file to read it:

```
A,B,1.2,1
A,C,1.5,0
C,D,0.7,0
D,E,0.6,0
```

The first two columns are 2 nodes. The third column is the cost for moving from one node to another. The fourth column is the reliable status (1=reliable, 0=unreliable).

I have ideas on how to implement the search itself, but I'm having a hard time to graph a tree in my code from the input file.

I'm not asking for any code, I hope that someone could give me an idea or pseudo code on how to accomplish this task.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Chris

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations

Comment: Do you want a gui?  Are you windows/linux/other?

Answer (score 0):

If your are planning to go any further with graphs, take a look at the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/).

Answer (score -1):

you can use ASCII values of characters to store as array index.

```
struct node{
    double weight;
    int reliability; //0 for reliable
}
```

now your graph will be 2D matrix of nodes.

in c/c++ you can use `yourChar - 'A'` to get index.
A as 0, B as 1 and so on...